# Programmatically call gesture on ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I would like to create an application that can call a gesture (swipe, pinch etc) without having to physically do the gesture.

The button would sit next to a webview to allow the gesture to be called inside it.

I have searched for a possible way to do this but cannot find and reference of calling a gesture programatically.

Does anyone have any advice of how this would be possible?

Answer (score 5):

Try manually calling the selector associated with your gesture in code.

Answer (score 1):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplicationd] sendAction:@selector(action) to:target :from:webview forEvent:touchEventOrNil];`

I prefer this for actions to plain performSelector